# Why func("abc" "def"); compiles

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, standards

just stumbled onto a miss in my code, a function was called like this

```
func("text1" "text2");
```

instead of

```
func("text1", "text2");
```

The thing is that it actually compiles and runs (MSVC 2008), the two strings are treated as one (ie a call to an overloaded func gets the input "text1text2").

Is this normal standard behaviour (ie. "abc" "def" == "abcdef") or isn't it ?

Comment: I assume there were some closing double quotes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is called [string literal concatenation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_syntax#String_literal_concatenation), and is a feature of the C and C++ compiler.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's normal behavior.  It's useful for having string constants span multiple lines.  You must have an overload of "func" somewhere that can accept a single parameter of `char*`.

Comment: Hopefully not `char*` but `const char*` :)

Comment: I guess there are two interpretations of that sentence!  I was commenting at how his code already compiled and ran, so therefore he must already have.....

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is standard behaviour.

Comment: +1. This comes handy with some macro based magic and long multiline strings.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's useful for building strings based on `#define`s.

```
#define MY_FOLDER "/some/folder/"
#define MY_FILE   MY_FOLDER "file.txt"
// expands to "/some/folder/file.txt"
```

Comment: And for the stringize operator too!